# SQL Date Range Query from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having some issues creating an SQL query to pull data from one table based on dates in another table... Table A contains the following columns:

```
CustomerID (ie. 1111)
romoCode (ie. CR-101)
StartDate (ie. 2018-01-05)
EndDate (ie. 2018-01-08)
```

Table B contains the following columns:

```
CustomerID (ie. 1111)
DateOfVisit (ie. 2018-01-06)
AmountSpent (ie. 50.00)
```

What I'd like to do is figure out how much each customer from Table A spent during the promotional period (between StartDate and EndDate). Here's just one example of one of the many queries I've tried but the results I'm getting just aren't correct...

```
select 
      a.CustomerID, a.PromoCode, sum(b.AmountSpent) as TotalSpent
from
    TableA as a
    left join
    TableB as b
    on 
    a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
where
    b.DateOfVisit between a.StartDate and a.EndDate
group by
    a.PromoCode, a.CustomerID
```

It seems as though some of the results I get with this query are correct but anytime I have duplicate CustomerID's (ie. the same customer redeemed different promotions on different dates) it seems to just combine their totals. 
I've tried various nesting, grouping, and joining methods with no luck so any suggestions at all would be helpful.

Comment: "it seems to just combine their totals".  That seems really reasonable.  Sample data and desired results would help us understand what you want.

Comment: Btw, your Left Join is actually an Inner Join due to the Where-condition

Comment: I don't see a problem with your query.  Give us sample data and unexpected results you are getting so we can try to reproduce it.

Comment: judging by your question, are you trying to get the amount of money spent by a customer per day during the whole promotion or just all the days during the promotion

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be both a data and a query issue. As it stands, your sample data shows you cannot stop duplicates, unless promo codes are prevented elsewhere from never overlapping dates for a single customer. To fix you will need to add a promo code to Table B, then use that in addition to Customer ID and Dates to join on. In fact, if the promo codes cannot repeat per customer then you can drop dates from the query once you add promo code to Table B.

If it helps, an example of what will happen with the current query.

Table A

```
CustomerID, PromoCode, StartDate, EndDate
1111, CR-101, 2018-01-05, 2018-01-09
1111, CR-121, 2018-01-07, 2018-01-11
```

Table B

```
CustomerID, DateOfVisit, AmountSpent
1111, 2018-01-06, 50.00
1111, 2018-01-08, 75.00
```

For this data I'm saying that the 6th is actually from CR-101 and 8th is from using CR-121. The Query Results, however, will be:

```
CustomerID, PromoCode, TotalSpent
1111, CR-101, 125.00
1111, CR-121, 75.00
```

If you'll notice, CR-101 comes out with 125 instead of 50 as the query matches both due to the date visit being in the date ranges for each promo code for the customer.